# Postgresql question: comparing string with an array between 2 tables

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

say I have 2 tables, T1 and T2.

T1.pet =  ["one"]["three"]

T2.pets = [["one, "two"]["three"]]

I want to see whether the elements in T1 exists in T2.

Right now I have a comparison that looks a bit like

AND
(T1.pet = T2.pets->>0 or

T1.pet = T2.pets->>1 or

T1.pet = T2.pets->>2 or

T1.pet = T2.pets->>n)

note: (T2.pets->>0 = ["one"]["three"] and T2.pets->>1 ["two"]]

How would I write this code in a more compact way where n is the largest length that exists in T2 (in this example, it is 2)

Comment: Are these JSON fields since you're using the `->>` operator?

Comment: yes, they are JSON fields.